# How can I mock a method that has a parameter with a private constructor?

Tags: java, redis, mockito

I have an abstract cache client with an implementation that I'm trying to add unit tests to, and it has a protected class implementation of the key. Like this:

```java
public abstract class SimpleCacheClient<V extends Serializable> {
    // Autowired RedissonClient and RedisKeyGenerator

    public V get(SimpleCacheKey key) {
        // return the cache entry from the autowired RedissonClient
    }

    public void set(SimpleCacheKey key, V value) {
        // set the cache entry
    }

    public SimpleCacheKey getCacheKey(Object...keys) {
        return new SimpleCacheKey(keyGenerator.generateKey(keys));
    }

    /**
    * Simple wrapper for cache key to guarantee that implementations
    * are using the key generator provided in this class
    */
    protected class SimpleCacheKey {
        private String key;

        SimpleCacheKey(String key) {
            this.key = key;
        }

        public String getKey() {
            return key;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return getKey();
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the implementation I'm trying to test:

```java
public class CacheClientImplementation extends SimpleCacheClient<ArrayList<DateTime>> {
    public void addEventDateTimes(String key, ArrayList<DateTime> eventDateTimes) {
        // Do stuff with eventDateTimes and then
        set(getCacheKey(key), eventDateTimes);
    }
    
    public ArrayList<DateTime> getEventDateTimes(String key) {
        ArrayList<DateTime> eventDateTimes = get(getCacheKey(key));
        // Do stuff with eventDateTimes.
        return eventDateTimes;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to test to make sure that `CacheClientImplementation` performs certain operations on the values provided to it before setting and getting.
I'm trying to mock the redis cache itself by hijacking the `get()` and `set()` methods to read and write from/to a `HashMap` so that I can check the contents of the "cache" in my tests.

```java
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class CacheClientImplementationTest{
    @Mock
    private RedissonClient redissonClient;

    @Mock
    private RedisKeyGenerator redisKeyGenerator;

    @Spy
    @InjectMocks
    private CacheClientImplementation cacheClient = new CacheClientImplementation();

    private final HashMap<String, ArrayList<DateTime>> cacheMap = new HashMap<>();

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        Mockito.doAnswer((ver) -> {
            cacheMap.put(ver.getArgumentAt(0, Object.class).toString(), ver.getArgumentAt(1, ArrayList.class));
            return null;
        }).when(cacheClient).set(Mockito.any(), Mockito.any(ArrayList.class));
        Mockito.doAnswer((ver) -> cacheMap.getOrDefault(ver.getArgumentAt(0, Object.class).toString(), null))
            .when(cacheClient).get(Mockito.any());
    }

    @After
    public void teardown() {
        cacheMap.clear();
    }
}
```

However, I end up with this problem when I run a test in the file.

```
C:\...\CacheClientImplementationTest.java:20: error: SimpleCacheClient.SimpleCacheKey has protected access in SimpleCacheClient
        }).when(cacheClient).set(Mockito.any(), Mockito.any(ArrayList.class));
```

Is there any way I can `doAnswer` for these methods without changing SimpleCacheKey?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This boils down to the visibility of the `SimpleCacheKey` class, you simply can't use it from a different package. So `Mockito.any()` can't use that class as a return type unless the unit test is in the same package as `SimpleCacheClient`.

One solution would be to move your unit test to the same package as `SimpleCacheClient`. If this is loaded from a different library that you can't change, you can re-create the same package structure to trick the compiler into thinking the package is the same, giving you access to `protected` classes.
But i believe this trick doesn't work with Java 9 modules.

A better solution would be to make a small modification to your `CacheClientImplementation` and unit test; encapsulate the part you can't influence and mock that part.

Since you don't really care about the `SimpleCacheKey` but just the `String key`, the following should work for your intentions:

```
public class CacheClientImplementation extends SimpleCacheClient<ArrayList<DateTime>> {
    public void addEventDateTimes(String key, ArrayList<DateTime> eventDateTimes) {
        // Do stuff with eventDateTimes and then
        setForKey(key, eventDateTimes);
    }

    public ArrayList<DateTime> getEventDateTimes(String key) {
        ArrayList<DateTime> eventDateTimes = getForKey(key);
        // Do stuff with eventDateTimes.
        return eventDateTimes;
    }

    protected ArrayList<DateTime> getForKey(String key) {
        return super.get(getCacheKey(key));
    }

    protected void setForKey(String key, ArrayList<DateTime> value) {
        super.set(getCacheKey(key), value);
    }
}
```

And in the unit test you rewrite to the `forKey` variants we just created:

```
Mockito.doAnswer(myAnswer1()).when(cacheClient).setForKey(Mockito.any(), Mockito.any(ArrayList.class));
Mockito.doAnswer(myAnswer2()).when(cacheClient).getForKey(Mockito.any());
```

I've made the new methods `protected` as to not confuse callers which method to use, so in this case the unit test must be in same (test) package as the `CacheClientImplementation`.

Comment: I ended up using this solution, except that I put the `getForKey` and `setForKey` methods (I just overloaded the `get` and `set`  methods though, since the signatures are different) in the abstract `SimpleCacheClient` instead of in the implementation, as that made more sense to me. They're still protected.